# Linking errors with lua & luabind - mingw

Tags: c++, lua, mingw, linker-errors, luabind

I am using [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) for binding my C++ classes to lua, I can get luabind and most lua functions to work, but if I try to use `luaL_openlibs()` I get:

```
undefined reference to 'luaL_openlibs'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

if I add -llua to the linker I get:

```
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x15c): multiple definition of 'lua_gettop'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000253.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x170): multiple definition of 'lua_settop'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000296.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x244): multiple definition of 'lua_pushvalue'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000278.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x274): multiple definition of 'lua_type'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000307.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x388): multiple definition of 'lua_touserdata'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000306.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x414): multiple definition of 'lua_pushnil'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000274.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x42c): multiple definition of 'lua_pushnumber'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000275.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x450): multiple definition of 'lua_pushinteger'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000271.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x46c): multiple definition of 'lua_pushboolean'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000268.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x85c): multiple definition of 'lua_concat'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000235.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x8e8): multiple definition of 'lua_pushlstring'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000273.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x97c): multiple definition of 'lua_error'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000240.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0xb5c): multiple definition of 'lua_pcall'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000267.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0xbdc): multiple definition of 'lua_pushcclosure'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000269.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0xf98): multiple definition of 'lua_pushstring'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000276.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x104c): multiple definition of 'lua_settable'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000295.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x10d4): multiple definition of 'lua_rawgeti'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000282.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x111c): multiple definition of 'lua_rawget'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000281.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x1278): multiple definition of 'lua_objlen'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000266.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x12ec): multiple definition of 'lua_tolstring'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000302.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x1368): multiple definition of 'lua_tointeger'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000301.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lapi.o):lapi.c:(.text+0x13a4): multiple definition of 'lua_tonumber'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000303.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lstate.o):lstate.c:(.text+0xf4): multiple definition of 'lua_close'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000234.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lauxlib.o):lauxlib.c:(.text+0x40): multiple definition of 'luaL_newstate'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000219.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lauxlib.o):lauxlib.c:(.text+0x20c): multiple definition of 'luaL_loadfile'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000216.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lauxlib.o):lauxlib.c:(.text+0x5e0): multiple definition of 'luaL_unref'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000229.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../liblua.a(lauxlib.o):lauxlib.c:(.text+0x664): multiple definition of 'luaL_ref'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libluabindd.dll.a(d000226.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I built luabind myself because I could find no prebuilt mingw binaries.

Comment: It seems like your luabind build already includes lua library. So you have multiple definitions of the same type.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I know, but why do I not have luaL_openlibs if I have almost all the rest and how can I fix it? I built it as the website directed... I suppose it might help if I figure out what else does not work...

Comment: I looked in the sources and I think the problem is luabind does not include lualib.h, which is the header that luaL_openlibs is defined in. but if I modify luabind to include this then it would only apply to the binary I build and if someone else were to build it or I were to get it from the repositories on Ubuntu I would still have this problem... is there some way to ignore the multiple definition and use liblua.a version of the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that I was linking to lua in a static library. I ended up downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.1.4/Windows%20Libraries/lua5_1_4_Win32_dllw4_lib.zip, rebuilding luabind to link to that, and setting my project to link to it also.